# Use queueEvent in onTouchEvent handler of GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, multithreading, glsurfaceview

I have a question about using queueEvent in onTouchEvent handler of GLSurfaceView.

The related codes are shown as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(); //in GUI thread
    float y = event.getY(); //in GUI thread
   
    queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rotationAroundTwoAxes(x, y); //in OpenGL thread
        }
    });
}
```

My question is since the variable x and y are accessed in two threads, do I need to do synchronization between them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need synchronization for that code.

Because GUI thread doesn't read those x or y. Your code just queues a Runnable per onTouchEvent with x and y values.

If that x or y is a global variable, you may need it to be synchronized (volatile, etc.). But in your code they are just local and disposal ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. x and y are local variables. I am confused what happen if the runnable access x and y in the GL thread and at the same time x and y are assigned a value in the GUI thread?